# Method that accepts generic argument as null

Tags: c#, generics

I want to write a method like this. However, the language does not like the `T obj = null` in the method arguments. And it does not like the `obj == null` either. I have tried `T : object` `T : INullable` to no avail. Is there any way I can get C# to accept this?

```
    public virtual static async Task<T> Get<T>(T obj = null) where T : struct
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        else
        {
            // Do other stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: `null` is default value for reference types, not the value ones

Comment: In other words it is the T : struct that gets you in trouble!

Comment: `where T : class` may solve it or `T obj = default` without generic constraints

Comment: Can you confirm that you must be able to use this with value types (I assume that's why you added the struct constraint)?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Good point. I do not need it to work with value types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `null` value as default one you should apply `where T : class` [generic constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters). Or even use `Get<T>(T obj = default)` without constraints (if [`default` literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-literal) and C# 7.1 is available).

If you still need a `T` as value type (and `struct` constaint), just declare method as `Get<T>(T? obj = null) where T : struct`. `T?` in this case means [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netcore-3.1) struct